# Prevent rounding off in string.format

Tags: c#

```cs
string xyz = "23.659";
return string.Format("{0:F"+2+"}", xyz);
```

output = 23.66

When I use string.format the value gets rounded off, but I need 23.65 as the output.
How to prevent rounding off in string.format?

Comment: You cannot format a number given as string. The number must be given as numeric type. `"{0:F"+2+"}"` is the same as `"{0:F2}"`

Answer (score 0):

You can round the value *manually*, e.g. with a help of [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32-system-midpointrounding)):

```
// If you have string (not decimal or double) we'll have parse
string xyz = "23.659";

return double.TryParse(xyz, out var value)
  ? string.Format("{0:F2}", Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero))
  : xyz;
```

If `xyz` is of type `float`, `double`, `decimal` which is more natural the code doesn't want parsing:

```
double xyz = 23.659;

return string.Format("{0:F2}", Math.Round(xyz, 2, MidpointRounding.ToZero));
```